# An event has run for certain amount of time. How to find the time for how long this event has run in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL. I ran one event it took long time.
How to find the time for how long this event has run?

Comment: I personally keep a log table for my events. and insert into it at the end of my event/procedure execution.

Comment: `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` provides the time (in seconds) that each _current_ process has run so far.  For checking time _after_ a query has run, you need to have the "slowlog" turned on.  See the details for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can create an evenlog-table. Then inside your event :

```
BEGIN
  SET @starttime = now();
  ....
  insert into event_log (name, starttime, endtime) values ('myevent', @starttime, now());
END
```

Like this you'll have a log of all your events over a longer period to compare.